# How to set up Geth in a Docker container on a VM such that RPC works?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, docker

The Geth team conveniently provides a [Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/ethereum/client-go/) for the latest Geth builds, but when using Docker on Windows or Mac OS (where Docker is using a virtual machine to host containers) how to run it such that RPC calls can be seen on the local workstation? Running `docker run -p 8545:8545 --name geth ethereum/cilent-go --rpc` doesn't seem to do it.

Testing with CURL:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "web3_clientVersion", "params": [] }' \
  "http://192.168.99.100:8545"
```

I get no response from the above command, it just spins until it times out.

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that the default RPC server is "localhost", which doesn't seem to work properly in a Docker container in a VM. Instead, the server name of "0.0.0.0" will bind to all IP addresses the container is given, which will work with Docker's networking better.

So, the one-line command to run would be:

```
docker run -p 8545:8545 --name geth ethereum/client-go --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0
```

For better security, your 'go to' command to get Geth up-and-running should probably not have the `--rpc` flag on by default. Instead, try doing something like:

```
docker run -td -p 8545:8545 -p 30303:30303 --name geth ethereum/client-go
docker exec -it geth /user/bin/geth attach
```

That will open up the sharing port such that other Ethereum nodes can find it, but not start the RPC server right away. That `docker exec` command will get you into the Geth console, where you can then run `admin.startRPC('0.0.0.0', 8545)`. If you want access to the running logs of the Geth node, run `docker logs -f geth`.